# Paypal commerce Api error in wordpress Wpforms

Tags: wordpress, paypal, wpforms

I'm using PayPal Commerce as a payment method in WPForms. Everything was working fine, but now I'm getting an API error when trying to make a payment. Does anyone know how to resolve this? When I make the paymet as an admin everything works.